# OSX Yosemite DNS cache Issues

Tags: macos, network, dns

I'm having a really frustrating DNS cache issue on my Macbook running Yosemite.

I'm a web developer so i'm always working with new sites and setting up new servers / domains etc.. so every now and then I will try to load a domain that hasn't propagated yet and I will get the standard "ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED" error.

I will then confirm the domain has propagated and try clearing my DNS cache using every single option I've found online:

- sudo killall -INFO mDNSResponder
- sudo discoveryutil udnsflushcaches
- sudo discoveryutil mdnsflushcache;sudo discoveryutil udnsflushcaches;say flushed

And NONE of them work! I simply can NEVER access that domain until I restart my Mac or wait 24 hours or something stupid!

I can access the domain FINE on my phone via both WIFI (same network) AND 3G / Mobile... so the issue is 100% with my Macbook and Yosemite!

It's so frustrating!!!!

Does anyone know a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

Yosemite doesn't use mDNSResponder, it uses discoveryd - which has caused so many people so many issues that Apple have done an about face & are re-introducing mDNSResponder in Yosemite 10.10.4

You can sign up for the [Appleseed Beta](https://appleseed.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/) if you really want it early.

Comment: So there is no way to manually go in and delete a single url from being cached?? This is a huge bug! Is restarting really the only fix?

Comment: there's a useful answer here, but it does seem to have been causing issues for a lot of people - http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/158166/85275